# pdf.js incompatible with nuxt 2.15.8

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I was using [pdfjs-dist](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist) v2.5.207 with nuxt v2.4.5 and it was working perfectly fine. Now, that I am trying to upgrade my application to nuxt v2.15.8, the server build is failing because of pdfjs. I tried upgrading pdfjs-dist to v2.14.305 but it's not helping.
The build error log is not giving any useful information. It seems like a build compatibility issue, can someone please suggest a solution here?

I was using worker-loader v3.0.3, which I tried upgrading to v3.0.8, but that also didn't solve the problem.

```
********************************************************/ /******/ // The module cache
| /******/var __webpack_module_cache__={};/******/ /******/ // The require function
| /******/function __w_pdfjs_require__(moduleId){/******/ // Check if module is in cache
 @ ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack.js 14:28-53
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/components/PDFDocument.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/components/PDFDocument.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/components/PDFDocument.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/components/preview-documents.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/components/preview-documents.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/components/preview-documents.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/pages/create-report/upload-documents.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/pages/create-report/upload-documents.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/pages/create-report/upload-documents.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/server.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/server.js
```